# Job responsibilities changing after accepted offer

Tags: job-offer, job-acceptance

I recently accepted an offer as a manager at a medium sized company. I do not start for some time and I have not given notice to my current employer yet.

This role was to report to PersonA who is a department manager. The bareboned intent of this manager role as I understood it from the job description and interviews was to assist PersonA by managing a few of the teams that report to them. As a dept manager they had all of the teams reporting to them and were looking to offload some of that to my role. This position as described was appealing to me and I accepted the offer.

Some time goes by after my acceptance and PersonB also with a title of department manager who is a peer to PersonA (in the same department) reached out to me. PersonB told me that I will be reporting to them instead of PersonA and I will be playing multiple roles (including manager) on 1 team instead of managing multiple teams.

This feels like a significant change from the role I had accepted not only in scope but who I am reporting into.

Are my concerns enough that I should reconsider the acceptance or am I overthinking these changes and their significance?

Comment: I feel this is a "should I" question (off topic here, check the [tour] and [help/dont-ask]) ... but anyways, this does smells fishy to me... if it were me I would strongly reconsider joining this company

Comment: "Are my concerns enough that I should reconsider the acceptance or am I overthinking these changes and their significance?" Yes, but don't phrase it like that. Don't say you're reconsidering, but at least, ask to interview them again and prepare a list of questions to ask them about the changes. And don't just interview the "boomerang employee". The boomerang employee may not have as much power as he thinks he has. He may have been given an offer he couldn't refuse, but some employers no longer trust boomerang employees (even if they're the ones who begged them to come back).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are my concerns enough that I should reconsider the acceptance

Yes of course. This is a fairly significant change and it's good practice to reevaluate the opportunity. If you feel the new job description and the new manager are good for you, then go for it. If you feel this is not what you want, then decline.

If you need more information, get more information. Personally I would not sign for a manager that I have never met before, so perhaps a quick get-to-know meeting or video chat with PersonB would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This really helped me get my head around it.